# Rewrite script to jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website I use following code. It works great with jQuery 2.2.3. Now I want to use jQuery 3, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me to rewrite this code to jQuery 3? Vanilla js solution would be also appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preloading').load("loading.html", function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#preloading').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove window `load` event handler its not required, just use callback method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because in jQuery 3.x the `load()` method is only used to retrieve content via an AJAX request, so your use of it as an event handler is invalid. As an aside - it wasn't needed in your original code using 2.x.

To fix the issue simply remove the `$(window).load()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preloading').load("loading.html", function() {
        $('#preloading').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, your code has deprecated/removed methods:

1. Deprecated `$(document).ready` (https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function)
2. Removed `.load()` (https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

After replacing:

```
$(function () {
    $('#preloading').load("loading.html", function () {
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $('#preloading').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
});
```